# Multithreading - don't understand the situation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

```
        var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
                     Thread.Sleep(4000);
                     Console.WriteLine("Done");
                     ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); 
                   }, ct);

        Thread.Sleep(1000); Look here! <--- 
        tokenSource2.Cancel();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wait");
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task was canceled");
        }
```

I can't understand why if I comment this line all works ok and exception is catched in the main thread, but if I left this line exception is thrown in child thread on the line with ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); We have one instance of the cancelation token in both cases. I'm a new in multithreadin, so I definetly miss somthing.

I tried the next code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";

        Console.WriteLine("Name of the current thread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(4000); 
            Console.WriteLine("Done");

            try
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // If I remove the try/catch here will be unhandled exception
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task was started then canceled");   
            }

        }, ct);//ontinueWith(OnProcessImageEnded);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        tokenSource2.Cancel();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wait");
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task was canceled");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Task was finished");

        Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
```

I process exception in the task's thread now, but it leads to Status of the task not to be set Canceled. I think it is because now the task can't catch the exception to process it. What is the right way?

I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191553.aspx this example and it has the same problem! if we press on 'c' during execution it will throws unhandled exception when we try to rethrow by calling  externalToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); ... I'm confused at all. I'm using x64 Win 7, 4.5 .net framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you comment the line, chances are our Task is cancelled even before it is started. Hence you get the exception. When you add sleep - mostly it will be started, so cancellation happens within the task with your call to `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`

Comment: ok, but I thought the behavior must be the same. Why does it have the meaning a task started or not? Here docs info: When a task instance observes an OperationCanceledException thrown by user code, it compares the exception's token to its associated token (look next comment. it is too long for one)

Comment: (the one that was passed to the API that created the Task). If they are the same and the token's IsCancellationRequested property returns true, the task interprets this as acknowledging cancellation and transitions to the Canceled state. If you do not use a Wait or WaitAll method to wait for the task, then the task just sets its status to Canceled.--- As I understand, It means that exception must not be thrown at all if don't have wait method and must be thrown in the main thread in try with Wait method. I took it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I think I didn't understand the conception. So, I've reviewed a few more examples and understood that if task's thread is not started then we should catch exception in the calling thread, but if it's already started we should threat cancellation exception in the task's thread not in calling one. Am I right?

Comment: no you should never catch exception thrown by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in the task code. If you do then what is the point? You see we in addition to passing token to task thread (via closure) we also pass it to Task itself (as the StartNew method parameter).

Comment: in any case there will be exception seen in calling thread at the point of task.Wait()

Comment: Yes, I were thinking the same way! But It didn't work like this or I'm doing something wrong. Please, help me to understand where is my mistake. Please, look at my post again. I added some code.

Comment: When you say "It didnt work like this" - what do you mean? In both cases exception is caught in calling thread when task.Wait is called. Are you debugging the program under visual studio? Then you may have enabled MDA at the place where exceptions are thrown as against where they are caught. please check under Debug > Exceptions. In any case without debugger, your first program should output "Task was canceled". Your second program is wrong - you should never catch exception thrown by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` - it does not make sense.

Comment: When you say "It didnt work like this" - what do you mean? > I mean that I get unhandled exception in task's thread. Task does not catch it for throwing under the main thread

Comment: `I get unhandled exception in task's thread` which is correct - that is how the task will be cancelled. this unhandled exception in tasks thread will be handled in main thread when you call task.Wait() on that task.

Comment: internally the task framework will store that exception in tasks state and re-throw it when you call task.Wait() in main thread.

Comment: Yes, I understand it) I thought like this at the begining. You've already answered on my question. The MDA is the main reason of this. I compiled the program and start it from exe file and all is correct! I didn't know about this tool, so this is why I was confused. Now I need to find a way to disable it. Thank you!

Comment: Great! You can fix the MDA by uncheking the  boxes under the "thrown" column in Debug > Exceptions dialog

Comment: I did, but it continues stoping on ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

Comment: make sure you have it unchecked against 'managed debugging assistance' and 'Common language runtime exceptions' - i think this exception will come under CLR exceptions

Comment: Yes, you are right. I unchecked OperationCanceledException exception in the CLR section and it doesn't stop on ThrowIfCancellationRequested() anymore. Thanks again! You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'll defer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) for this one.

> Task.Wait Method
>
> AggregateException
>
> The Task was canceled -or- an exception was thrown during the
> execution of the Task. If the task was canceled, the
> AggregateException contains an OperationCanceledException in its
> InnerExceptions collection.

Essentially it is a race condition where if you make it to `task.Wait` in time you win.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your answer. What do you mean? When cancellation is called task is still running(maybe the thread sleep, but it is no matter, I think). I'm talking about Sleep with 1sc delay in tyhe main thread. How can it affect on the where exception is catched? We can delete task.Wait() and the exception is still catched in the task's thread, but as I understand. it must not catch it, because if we don't call Wait method an internal handler of a task catchs it and set Canseled status. Please, make it clear for me :)